# The nozzle keeps clogging, midway through the print while printing with PETG filament

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, extruder, nozzle, petg

I've recently purchased Creality Ender 3 V2. When I print PLA, I face no issue at all but while printing PETG, the nozzle keeps clogging after the second or third layer. I even tried printing PETG by keeping the fan off for all the layers but with no success. The recommended nozzle temperature is 220 °C - 250 °C and the heated bed temperature is 60 °C - 80 °C by the filament manufacturer. For better adhesion, I'm using a thin layer of glue stick for the bed. Due to the unavailability of a Capricorn tube in my city, I've not upgraded the stock PTFE tube yet.

My current print settings in Prusaslicer are as follows:

- Filament: Generic PETG (modified)

Temperature:

- Nozzle: first layer 235 °C, other layers 230 °C.
- Bed: First layer 65 °C, other layers 60 °C.

Fan:

- Disable fan for the first: 3 layers.
- Fan speed: min 20 %, max 50 %
- Bridge fan speed: 100 %

Retraction:

- Length: 3 mm
- Retraction Speed: 30 mm/s.

[image: Photo of the printer's extruder with filament backed up]

Comment: What happens when you print with retraction off?

Comment: I've not tried with retraction off.

Comment: With PETG I run the nozzle at 250 °C, and all my fans at 100%.  I even added more fans to the enclosure.